# Prevent javascript code misuse by users

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, encryption

Users on my website can click on a button. If they do, they will get a points reward.

This button, when clicked, is making an AJAX call to the server to give the reward (stored in database).

The button is a "make a tweet" button, so I want to make sure they really do their tweet thing.

My problem is I want to make sure that the button really has been clicked. Since the javascript code is entirely visible by the users, I guess it would be easy for them to just make the AJAX call without clicking on it.

So, anything I can do ? Is obfuscation my only option, or can I encrypt something, or use token or something ?

If it may help, users are logged in and pages are served with PHP.

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to click the button several times to sum up the reward? Strange concept... otherwise where is the problem? No one cares if the button is pressed by a mouse pointer or a script.

Comment: Make sure the points can only be awarded once (within a certain time period) -- as long as the button is the EASIEST way to get the points, there's no incentive to do it programmatically.

Comment: I do not care if the button is press more than once. It is easy to disable it and to check that on server side. But, i want to make sure the button has been clicked, and that it is not a script that made the call.

Comment: So your reward is there available for anyone who pushes the button?

Comment: It is a "Make a tweet" button.

Comment: @Rory yes to anyone that is logged in and only once.

Comment: @Jean, This is really difficult in the world of static internet protocols, delete-able cookies and sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are out of luck - there is no foolproof solution that will prevent someone from writing a simple script that downloads the page, parses it for any security tokens and then calls the AJAX request.

You can only make the job slightly harder by adding some additional data that is rendered by the server and submitted back via AJAX call.

You might look into adding a CAPTCHA image to the button - this would prevent the bots from submitting data but also would make the life of the real user harder.

Comment: Allright, thanks. The Captcha would be to hard on the users (ask them to make a tweet AND a f... captcha, that wont do), but I think you pretty much summed it up.

Comment: You could allow the user (by IP or username) to make X requests in Y minutes and if they want to make more, then show a CAPTCHA.

Comment: Yeah, others suggested that, but thats not the point, since I keep record of the reward in the database (and only allow 1, server side). That part is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to attach a [CSRF token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) to your request, to be sure a click has been performed from that page, and within the current session.

You may either implement an expiring token - you set it once in your session, when the user asks for it, it gets invalidated and you're done.

Comment: I feel like the user will be able to see that token, no ?

Comment: Yes, this would basically prevent automated scripting leakage. See my edit about making an expiring token in your `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @moonwave99 That doesn't prevent the user from making a script to automatically submit the request. CSRF token prevent other site from forcing the user to make an action. It doesn't apply the the OP problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you only allow the button to be clicked once within a certain time frame? This could be enforced within the PHP and would be pretty safe.

Even if you use a token or something the user will probably be able to find it and run the script directly. There needs to be some kind of server validation such as time validation to be really safe.

Comment: That would not prevent a script from submitting the button, no ?

Comment: Well, if the script was called you check when the user last pressed the button and see if it was within a certain time frame, say a day. If it was then don't give them the points that the button usual gives them.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the user can even reproduce the token, it is strictly speaking not a perfect protection.
Obfuscation of the code might help.
I presume that you want to prevent programmatical or multiple voting..
You can record ip to prevent multiple voting & use csrf token, but provided your users are logged in it is presumable they are trusted and in the case of manipulation, you simply delete their account.

I think you should try with captcha and also, identify user who is voting and restrict him from multiple votes server side.

But faking the click is still doable.

Comment: Thanks for that, I 100% agree.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement a "captcha" based system which ensures that (1) only a human has clicked the button (2) only once it is pressed

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/04/best-5-jquery-captcha-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

1- Looks like these users are registered members of your website. If this is the case, just create a **points** table in your database with id, username and other relational columns. Let your script make `request` work if they haven't got points earlier (by checking first **that the user is logged in**, then checking the username against users db and if they exist with the relation deny the request else accept it, inside the **points** table).

2- If they are non-registered users, use Google captcha for checking.

Comment: it seems that the user should be able to get points for multiple times. the rest is easily scriptable (except for captcha)

Comment: @Knaģis then the relational columns would handle that.

Comment: Thanks Yousuf, but my problem was not to prevent multiple submissions, but to prevent scripting submission (instead of real user submission).

Comment: @Jean, This is really difficult in the world of static internet protocols, delete-able cookies and sessions.